# Keyboard shortcut for C# property declaration?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I've previously used a shortcut for creating C# properties in Visual Studio 2010, but I cannot remember what this was.

If I was to type:

```
public string Foo
```

I could type a shortcut which would generate:

```
public string Foo { get; set; }
```

What is the shortcut to achieve something like this, in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are talking about [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx) - there are several built in.

For a auto-property just type `prop` and tab. You will need to complete the property name and type.

Comment: @Curt There's a list [Visual C# Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx).

Comment: @Oded Did you mean to say `tab twice`? (that's what the `intellisense` in Visual Studio instructs).